# How to avoid multiple same xhr requests with Javascript and Twig

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I wanted to know how to avoid multiple same xhr requests to prevent load, also if you can advice me if this code is safe ?

This code load users avatars on the page.

code:

```
{% for bulle in bulles|reverse %}
            {% if bulle.postedBy in app.user.followers %}
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/api/"+"{{ bulle.postedby }}"+"/avatar",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    timeout: 10000,
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.avatar == undefined) {
                            $('#img{{ bulle.postedBy ~ loop.index }}').each(function () {
                                $('#img{{ bulle.postedBy ~ loop.index }}').attr('src', 'img/avatar/default.png');
                            });
                        } else {
                            $('#img{{ bulle.postedBy ~ loop.index }}').each(function () {
                                $('#img{{ bulle.postedBy ~ loop.index }}').attr('src', '/uploads/user_avatar/' + response.avatar);
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        console.log("API Error, can't get users avatar");
                    }
                });
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

[xhr requests screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNtuX.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your server might get pretty overwhelmed with number of requests, fast! Can't you somehow include the `avatar` info inside of your `bulle`?

Comment: The avatar info is in the user table, do you have any idea of how to "sync" avatar between two table (user and bulles) ?

Comment: EDIT: found a solution https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/associations.html, thanks @JovanPerovic :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: found a solution symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/associations.html, thanks @JovanPerovic :)